# CSS codes don't work after i saved file on apache sever

Tags: jquery, css

i'm developing my website using php and i'm also using local sever (xampp).  sometimes many css codes don't work after i saved them.
 when i open the browser console i can't find the css codes, but when i open source tab in console and open my css file i found the code, and also when click on view page source and open css file i found the code too, and sometimes those issues happened with jquery codes

this issue happened before but when i rename the jquery file, the issue gone but it seems this solution won't work every time. i tried to restart the apache server thinking this could solve the problem but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the Caching of static files (in your case, CSS) in the browser.

Various Ways to handle this:

1. **Hard reload:** Use keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Shift-R, Shift-F5 to reload the browser to see newly written CSS in effect.
2. Close all browser windows and open the link in **Incognito**(CTRL+SHIFT+N in chrome), every time you have new CSS written.